# Do either directX or openGL have methods for creating basic windows and menu components?

Tags: opengl, directx

If not does QT have support for direct X or openGL?  Or am I stuck using the windows API with C++ and java's AWT components?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a low-level graphics API; it's meant for drawing primitives (points, lines, and triangles) onto the screen as fast as possible. It doesn't have several concepts needed for GUI widgets (such as objects, text, or peripheral events).

I can't speak for DirectX, but I can't imagine the situation being much different there.

However, there are libraries for GUI components which use OpenGL for rendering, such as [AntTweakBar](http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/). Alternatively, I think some GUI libraries may offer an "OpenGL Canvas" component, which you can place inside of panels, etc.

Comment: "there are libraries for GUI components"                                                                                             Would SDL be an example of one of these?

Comment: also, how do i upvote you or whatnot?  That was a very clear, concise answer.